# javascript horoscope calculator says "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to this, the idea was to make a fairly simple horoscope calculator. you select your birth month and day from select options, click a 'calculate' button and your zodiac sign should pop up in a paragraph element.
the problem is, instead of giving you your sign, it says "undefined." no errors pop up in the console.
why is this happening and how do I fix it? please and thank you :)

```
const Day = document.getElementById("day");
const Button = document.getElementById("button");

const January = document.getElementById("Jan");
const February = document.getElementById("Feb");
const March = document.getElementById("Mar");
const April = document.getElementById("Apr");
const May = document.getElementById("May");
const June = document.getElementById("June");
const July = document.getElementById("July");
const August = document.getElementById("Aug");
const September = document.getElementById("Sept");
const October = document.getElementById("Oct");
const November = document.getElementById("Nov");
const December = document.getElementById("Dec");

const Result = document.getElementById('result');

function GetSign (Month, Day) {
if (Month == March && Day >=21 || Month == April && Day <=19) {
Result.innerHTML = "Aries";
}
else if (Month == March && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == April && Day >=20 || Month == May && Day <=20) {
Result.innerHTML = "Taurus";
}
else if (Month == April && Day > 30) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == May && Day >=21 || Month == June && Day <=21) {
Result.innerHTML = "Gemini";
}
else if (Month == May && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == June && Day >=22 || Month == July && Day <=22) {
Result.innerHTML = "cancer";
}
else if (Month == June && Day > 30) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == July && Day >=23 || Month == August && Day <=22) {
Result.innerHTML = "Leo";
}
else if (Month == July && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == August && Day >=23 || Month == September && Day <=22) {
Result.innerHTML = "virgo";
}
else if (Month == August && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == September && Day >=23 || Month == October && Day <=22) {
Result.innerHTML = "libra";
}
else if (Month == September && Day > 30) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == October && Day >=23 || Month == November && Day <=21) {
Result.innerHTML = "scorpio";
}
else if (Month == October && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == November && Day >=22 || Month == December && Day <=21) {
Result.innerHTML = "Sagittarius";
}
else if (Month == November && Day > 30) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == December && Day >=22 || Month == January && Day <=19) {
Result.innerHTML = "capricorn";
}
else if (Month == December && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == January && Day >=20 || Month == February && Day <=18) {
Result.innerHTML = "Aquarius";
}
else if (Month == January && Day > 31) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
else if (Month == February && Day >=19 || Month == March && Day <=20) {
Result.innerHTML = "pisces";
}
else if (Month == February && Day > 29) {
Result.innerHTML = "invalid date";
}
}
Button.addEventListener('click', GetSign);
```

```
        <option value = "January" id = "Jan">January</option>
        <option value = "February" id = "Feb">February</option>
        <option value = "March" id = "Mar">March</option>
        <option value = "April" id = "Apr">April</option>
        <option value = "May" id = "May">May</option>
        <option value = "June" id = "june">June</option>
        <option value = "July" id = "July">July</option>
        <option value = "August" id = "Aug">August</option>
        <option value = "September" id = "Sept">September</option>
        <option value = "October" id = "Oct">October</option>
        <option value = "November" id = "Nov">November</option>
        <option value = "December" id = "Dec">December</option>
      </select>
      <select name = "day" id = "day">
        <option value = "1">1</option>
        <option value = "2">2</option>
        <option value = "3">3</option>
        <option value = "4">4</option>
        <option value = "5">5</option>
        <option value = "6">6</option>
        <option value = "7">7</option>
        <option value = "8">8</option>
        <option value = "9">9</option>
        <option value = "10">10</option>
        <option value = "11">11</option>
        <option value = "12">12</option>
        <option value = "13">13</option>
        <option value = "14">14</option>
        <option value = "15">15</option>
        <option value = "16">16</option>
        <option value = "17">17</option>
        <option value = "18">18</option>
        <option value = "19">19</option>
        <option value = "20">20</option>
        <option value = "21">21</option>
        <option value = "22">22</option>
        <option value = "23">23</option>
        <option value = "24">24</option>
        <option value = "25">25</option>
        <option value = "26">26</option>
        <option value = "27">27</option>
        <option value = "28">28</option>
        <option value = "29">29</option>
        <option value = "30">30</option>
        <option value = "31">31</option>
      </select>
      <button id ="button" onclick = "getElementById('result').innerHTML = GetSign()">calculate!</button>
        <p id = "result"></p>
```

Comment: There's quite a few issues with what you've posted, but we need to see some relevant HTML in order to really help.  Can you post just a small example of months and days, and the button?

Comment: ok, I added it to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There are a few things that can be done cleaner here but this would be a good way to make your current situation work out. The main problem is you are not looking at the value of these selections, you have your javascript pointing to variables that are defined by the ids of these selections not the value- so they are not defied.

JS notes:

- notice the three new consts here for just the month, day, and result, each point to the ID of their corresponding selections.
- notice in the new JS all the months variables are now 'month.value'
- notice on the other side of that what is being compared to the value is a string for the month, because that is how JS will read the value. Same thing for day is now 'day.value' and being compared to a number because that is how JS will bring in that value.
- You could possible make this cleaner by defining your signs as consts and use those in your if/else statements and using those consts in the comparison, this would just make your code a little shorter, but this answer was on how to make what you have work.

HTML:

```html
<select name="month" id="month">
   <option value="January" id="Jan">January</option>
   <option value="February" id="Feb">February</option>
   <option value="March" id="Mar">March</option>
   <option value="April" id="Apr">April</option>
   <option value="May" id="May">May</option>
   <option value="June" id="june">June</option>
   <option value="July" id="July">July</option>
   <option value="August" id="Aug">August</option>
   <option value="September" id="Sept">September</option>
   <option value="October" id="Oct">October</option>
   <option value="November" id="Nov">November</option>
   <option value="December" id="Dec">December</option>
  </select>
  <select name="day" id="day">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="23">23</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button">
   calculate!
  </button>
  <p id="result"></p>
```

JS:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
const month = document.getElementById('month')
const day = document.getElementById('day')
const result = document.getElementById('result')

function GetSign(Month, Day) {
 if (
  (month.value == 'March' && day.value >= 21) ||
  (month.value == 'April' && day.value <= 19)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Aries'
 } else if (month.value == 'March' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'April' && day.value >= 20) ||
  (month.value == 'May' && day.value <= 20)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Taurus'
 } else if (month.value == 'April' && day.value > 30) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'May' && day.value >= 21) ||
  (month.value == 'June' && day.value <= 21)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Gemini'
 } else if (month.value == 'May' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'June' && day.value >= 22) ||
  (month.value == 'July' && day.value <= 22)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'cancer'
 } else if (month.value == 'June' && day.value > 30) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'July' && day.value >= 23) ||
  (month.value == 'August' && day.value <= 22)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Leo'
 } else if (month.value == 'July' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'August' && day.value >= 23) ||
  (month.value == 'September' && day.value <= 22)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'virgo'
 } else if (month.value == 'August' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'September' && day.value >= 23) ||
  (month.value == 'October' && day.value <= 22)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'libra'
 } else if (month.value == 'September' && day.value > 30) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'October' && day.value >= 23) ||
  (month.value == 'November' && day.value <= 21)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'scorpio'
 } else if (month.value == 'October' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'November' && day.value >= 22) ||
  (month.value == 'December' && day.value <= 21)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Sagittarius'
 } else if (month.value == 'November' && day.value > 30) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'December' && day.value >= 22) ||
  (month.value == 'January' && day.value <= 19)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'capricorn'
 } else if (month.value == 'December' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'January' && day.value >= 20) ||
  (month.value == 'February' && day.value <= 18)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'Aquarius'
 } else if (month.value == 'January' && day.value > 31) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 } else if (
  (month.value == 'February' && day.value >= 19) ||
  (month.value == 'March' && day.value <= 20)
 ) {
  result.innerHTML = 'pisces'
 } else if (month.value == 'February' && day.value > 29) {
  result.innerHTML = 'invalid date'
 }
}
button.addEventListener('click', GetSign)
```